# asset_path returns wrong path for folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, soundmanager2

I have .swf files under `vendor/assets/images/swf/`. I need the asset path of that folder.

But this (.js.coffee.erb)

```
#= soundmanager2

$ ->
  soundManager.setup
    url: '<%= asset_path "swf/" %>'
```

is rendering this (.js):

```
(function() {
  var $ = jQuery;
  $(function() {
    return soundManager.setup({
      url: '/swf/'
    });
  });
}).call(this);
```

I am using rails 4.0.0.rc1. I am on development mode. The path `/assets/swf/soundmanager2.swf` returns 200, while `/swf/soundmanager2.swf` returns 404. The helper `image_path` returns `/images/swf/`, but `/images/swf/soundmanager2.swf` also returns 404.

Comment: Try `<%= asset_path('swf/soundmanager2.swf') %>`

Comment: It gets a valid path to that file, but it doesn't help me because SoundManager2 is supposed to choose either one of four different files under that path.

Comment: I am wondering how is this related to Rails asset-pipeline?

Comment: I need to resolve a path with the rails asset pipeline helper `asset_path` and the way I am doing is not working.

Comment: Assuming this is working, why doesn't it work for me?  https://github.com/glaszig/soundmanager-rails/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/soundmanager.js.erb

Comment: It seems to me that installing the gem is enough for the sound manager to work properly. Why you have to add the setup in your `.js` file?

Comment: I am not using that gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not worth the trouble, because you would have to disable digest to get the name of the files right. So the solution is to fix the library. In the case of Sound Manager 2, I did this:

Some CoffeeScript that I require:

```
#= require soundmanager2

jQuery ->
  soundManager.swfNames =
    "/soundmanager2.swf":              "<%= asset_path('swf/soundmanager2.swf') %>"
    "/soundmanager2_debug.swf":        "<%= asset_path('swf/soundmanager2_debug.swf') %>"
    "/soundmanager2_flash9.swf":       "<%= asset_path('swf/soundmanager2_flash9.swf') %>"
    "/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf": "<%= asset_path('swf/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf') %>"

  soundManager.setup
    debugMode: <% if Rails.env.development? %>true<% else %>false<% end %>
    url: '/'
```

In my copy of soundmanager2.js (V2.97a.20130512), inside the definition of `normalizeMovieURL`:

```
url = ...                // After url is set

url = sm2.swfNames[url]; // Workaround
```

Answer (score 2):

on rails 4 all the asset helpers (`image_path`, `asset_path` and the likes) appear to only return a `config.assets.prefix`-prefixed path if the asset you're accessing is actually resolvable by sprockets.
put simply: it must exist in you asset path on the disk after precompilation.

therefore, `asset_path('swf/')` will not work since it is a directory and not a file.

also, i experienced the following: rails < 4 (sprockets, rather) copied original images (and thus swf files) *and* created a digested version of that same file. because of this soundmanager was still able to find the non-digested swf files even though i have `config.assets.digest = true`.
with rails 4, these original images are not copied anymore because [they changed some precompile internals](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7968) which leads soundmanager to throw up if it wants to fallback to flash.

to properly fix this soundmanager needs to be patched, like michelpm proposes.
for [soundmanager-rails](https://github.com/glaszig/soundmanager-rails) i started working on a fix including a proper patch for soundmanager which you can find [over on github](https://github.com/glaszig/soundmanager-rails/compare/e2e403...e64b873).